# change sound file for while loop in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, audio, while-loop, counter

My code has 2 textfields. One that states how many times the sound will be played and the other states how long the interval is between the sounds. I would like the sound to be altered every other time time. So right now the sounds just plays aaaaaaaa. I want it to play ababababababa

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var whiste: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield2: UITextField!
    var arrPlayer: [AVAudioPlayer] = []
    var player = AVAudioPlayer()
    var timer = Timer()
    var count: Int = 0
    var judo = 0

    @IBAction func i() {
        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "regularWHistle", ofType: "wav")!)

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        } catch {
            print("No sound found by URL")
        }

        if let textValue = self.textField.text, let inputNumber = Int(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            playWith(repeatCount: inputNumber)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter number.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

        }}

    func playWith(repeatCount: Int) {
        var timeInterval = 0.36
        if let textValue = self.textfield2.text, let inputNumber = Double(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            timeInterval = inputNumber
        }

        player.play()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.count += 1
            print(self.count)
            if self.count != repeatCount {
                self.player.play()
            } else {
                self.count  = 0
                self.player.stop()
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: How should the two sounds be alternated? Do you want every other call to `func i()` to pick the other sound or do you want each play in `playWith` to alternate each sound?

Comment: each play in playWith to alternate the sound. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish to alternate the audio in each play inside `playWith` then you need to have two audio players, one for each sound.

Then alternate which one you play based on the count.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var whiste: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textfield2: UITextField!
    var arrPlayer: [AVAudioPlayer] = []
    var playerA: AVAudioPlayer!
    var playerB: AVAudioPlayer!
    var judo = 0

    @IBAction func i() {
        let alertSoundA = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "regularWHistle", withExtension: "wav")!
        let alertSoundB = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "otherWHistle", withExtension: "wav")!

        do {
            playerA = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSoundA)
            playerB = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSoundB)
        } catch {
            print("No sound found by URL")
        }

        if let textValue = self.textField.text, let inputNumber = Int(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            playWith(repeatCount: inputNumber)
        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter number.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

        }}

    func playWith(repeatCount: Int) {
        var timeInterval = 0.36
        if let textValue = self.textfield2.text, let inputNumber = Double(textValue), inputNumber > 0 {
            timeInterval = inputNumber
        }

        var count = 0
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            print(count)
            if count != repeatCount {
                let player = count % 2 == 0 ? playerA : playerB
                player.play()
                count += 1
            } else {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        })
        timer.fire()
    }
}
```